# Rocket.Chat Incoming Webhook: answer with specific responce (for facebook integration)

Tags: facebook, integration, webhooks, rocket.chat, facebook-webhooks

My goal is to sent facebook webhook to the "incoming webhooks" of Rocket.Chat

But facebook needs a "Verification Request" with a specific response and a key. Is it possible change the standard incoming script (see here: https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/integrations/#incoming-script-details) so the response will be send to facebook?

Thank you and enjoy your day:)

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same and I just found possible steps to the solution.

Two issues give hints, that incoming webhooks can create HTTP calls:
https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/4776
https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/pull/5876/files

```
HTTP: (method, url, options)
```

or

```
HTTP('get', 'url', optionsObj)
```

But I am not able to build a script to try this.

Another possible way to the solution could be a webhook proxy. It will take care of the response to Facebook and forward the webhook to rocketchat. Here is one example, but still, I am not able to create a proxy for our case.

https://github.com/ulope/rocketchat-webhook-proxy/blob/master/src/rocketchat_webhook_proxy/app.py

I hope this helps to get to the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to respond Facebook with the INT they previously send you in $hub.challenge

I've managed to archive this using n8n (by adding an specific webhook response) but the best middle integration at the moment is from make (previously integromat) and then to rocket chat.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I solved it with N8N. N8N has a Facebook node and Webhook nodes, which allow to easily set up a workflow which sends back any needed message to the web hook sender. I so created workflows, that forward new direct messages from Facebook via N8N to RocketChat. you can use the full extend of the facebook API. the hardest part was to create a longterm access key.